# Writing CRC data to .txt file

Tags: c++, fstream

This seems like it should be a basic C++ process, but I'm not familiar with the data output.

When I print the data without outputting to a text file, I get the correct values.

```
example: 00150017000 181
```

When printing to a text file, this is what I get:

```
11161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116111611161116
```

Here is my code:

```
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("C:\\CRC.txt");
for (i = 0; i < 200; i++, id++)
{
    myfile << sprintf(idstring, "%011d", id);
    myfile << printf("%s %03d\n", idstring, computeCrc(idstring));
}
myfile.close();
```

Everything else works fine and I know the CRC is generated correctly. Just a matter of getting the correct output.

I was able to output the console screen to a text file by adding "> CRC.txt" to the Debugging Properties Command Arguments, but I just wanted to know how I could incorporate the ofstream method into this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @rozina whoops looks like it is: int_cdecl

Comment: I would remove the for loop and start debuging on a fixed number. Also a question, why do you save the result of sprintf to the file?

Comment: to be honest, not sure. using source code i didn't write and trying to output it is all i am doing. @rozina

Comment: @rozina i apologize for lack of detail

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't save to the file what you think you save. First you save the result of `sprintf()` function, which in your case is 11. Then you save the result of the `printf()` function which in your case is 11 + 1 (space) + 3 + 1 (\n) = 16. So the result is 200 times 1116.

What you wanted to do

```
char tempBuf[12];
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("C:\\CRC.txt");
for (i = 0; i < 200; i++, id++)
{
    sprintf(tempBuf, "%011d", id);
    myfile << tempBuf << ' ';        
    sprintf(tempBuf, "%03d", computeCrc(tempBuf));
    myFile << tempBuf << '\n';
}
myfile.close();
```

Comment: "%s %03d\n" would this have any significance? I tried this code out and while 'idstring' was outputted correctly, computeCrc(idstring) is now outputted as single random symbols and characters.

Comment: conputerCrc(idstring) is actually an unsigned char. should i be converting that into an int? using atoi? or something like that?

Comment: so i attempted casting the computeCrc(idstring) into an int, but it did not return correct 3-digit values.

Comment: @terbubbs Yes ofc, you are correct, result of `computeCrc()` needs to be converted to a string. You can do that using `sprintf()`. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are ouputing the return of `sprintf()` and `printf()` to the file.  The returns of `sprintf()` and `printf()` are `int` and not the string you are creating.  To output the string you need to change your code to

```
for (i = 0; i < 200; i++, id++)
{
    sprintf(idstring, "%011d", id);
    myfile << idstring;
    myfile << computeCrc(idstring) << endl;
}
```